# C++ passing template class to void function

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

I would like to create a class call Array and pass the objects arr and arr1 it to a function called "fun". But my compiler told me that it expected primary-expression before "&" token". What did I miss?

.h file

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define ARRAY_H_INCLUDED

template <typename T, int SIZE>
class Array
{
  T values[SIZE];
};

template <typename T, int SIZE>
void fun (const Array<T, SIZE>& a,const Array<T, SIZE>& a1,int index)
{
}

#endif // ARRAY_H_INCLUDED


template <typename T, int SIZE>
void fun (const StaticArray<T, SIZE>& a,const StaticArray<T, SIZE>& a1,int index)
{
}
```

.CPP

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Array.h"

template <typename T, int SIZE>
void fun (const Array<T, SIZE>&,const Array<T, SIZE>&,int);

int main()
{
  int i=-1;
  Array<double, 5> arr;
  Array<bool, 5> arr1;
  fun(Array<double, 5>& arr,Array<double, 5>& arr1,i);  //error expected primary-expression before '&' token
}
```

Comment: You can just pass arr and arr1 into the function right? No need to redeclare that they are Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun(Array<double, 5>& arr,Array<double, 5>& arr1,i);
```

Should be

```
fun(arr,arr1,i);
```

Your error is that you are passing the arrays in incorrectly.

Comment: That is my initial thought, but if i use fun(arr,arr1,i); it said there is not matching function for call to fun(Array<double,5>&,Array<bool,5>,int&)

Comment: In your function declaration you have declared that both arrays should have the same type. When you try to pass in an array with a double and another array with a bool, bool is not the same type as double. If you want to be able to pass in two arrays with separate types, you should declare two different templates.